# change event getting called twice on mat-input

Tags: angular-material

I am using change event on mat-input
However it is getting called twice.
my issue can be found in this link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qgznvr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I saw a similar thread but couldn't conclude much

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use focusout event instead of change.

```
<dumb-comp (focusout)="parentChange($event)"></dumb-comp>
```